# Error Recieving Broadcast intent. Eclipse Paho

Tags: android, android-studio, mqtt, iot, paho

I am trying to use eclipse paho library for the android app designed for my IoT project. Android app is simply sending gyroscope and accelerometer data to the broker at iot.eclipse.org. 
I use the following code to establish a connection with the MQTT Server. 
 `public void establishMQTTConnection(){

```
    clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    Log.d(TAG,clientId+"");
    client =
            new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(),  "iot.eclipse.org:1883",
                    clientId);

   // MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    //options.setUserName("aiupvrxz");
    //options.setPassword("dOW0vFQzRGKA".toCharArray());
    try {

        token = client.connect();
        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                // We are connected
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");

            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Problem is app never establishes the connection. 
I get the following error in the logcat.

```
05-24 12:48:20.772 10236-10236/iot.dulanga.com.androidclientv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000010 (has extras) } in org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService$NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver@41fc9348
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4573)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10121 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
   at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:432)
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:295)
   at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:264)
   at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService$NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver.onReceive(MqttService.java:794)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4573) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest....

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
    </service>
</application>
```

`

Can anyone please help me to figure out the problem with my code. Thank you a lot!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception has the key section in the middle:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10121 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
```

Make sure you have added the required section to the application manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you a lot for your answer. I already added that permission in the manifest. Still I get the same error.

Comment: If you've added that in the right place then the exception should have changed

Comment: No Sir, I still get the same exception. I have edited the question. I have included the manifest as well. It will be really appreciated if you can help me through this. Thank you very much

Comment: Anybody solved this problem? It happens to me just with Android 8

Answer (score 2):

In my case i forgot add below 2 lines to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Of course you need add these permisions too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and in application scope add this line :

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
```